# What do boolean operations on lists mean?

Tags: python, boolean

I was going through the source of `pyftpdlib` and I found this:

`if self.rejected_users and self.allowed_users:
     raise AuthorizerError("rejected_users and allowed_users options are mutually exclusive")`

`rejected_users` and `allowed_users` are lists.
What's confusing me is how the `and` operator operates on two lists. I'd appreciate it if someone helped me out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**All** objects in Python have a boolean 'value'; they are either true or false in a boolean context.

Empty lists are false. This applies to all sequences and containers, including tuples, sets, dictionaries and strings.

Numeric 0 is false too, so 0, 0.0, 0j are all false as well, as are `None` and of course `False` itself:

```
>>> bool([])
False
>>> bool([1, 2])
True
>>> bool(0)
False
>>> bool('')
False
```

Everything else is considered true in a boolean context; so a list that is *not* empty is true, and two non-empty lists together with `and` is considered true as well.

You can make custom types  look like empty containers by implementing [`__len__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) and returning `0`, or look like a number by implementing [`__nonzero__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__)<sup>*</sup> and returning `False` when the instance is to be the boolean equivalent of numeric zero.

Just remember that `and` and `or` shortcircuit; if the first expression locks in the result then that value is returned and the second expression is ignored altogether. For `and`, that means that in the expression `x and y`, `y` is ignored if `x` is a false value (like an empty list), because the whole expression can never be true in that case. For `x or y`, `y` is ignored if `x` is a true value.

These rules are all covered by the [Boolean operations reference documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations).

<sup>*<sub>In Python 3, use [`__bool__`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) instead</sub></sup>.

Comment: I might want to add a link to some Python docs: http://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html

Comment: @xtofl: I prefer to link to more current documentation; I've added a reference link.

Comment: Though perhaps annoyingly, `bool([0]) == True`

Comment: @NickT: it's not an empty list, noone ever said anything about the contents. Empty -> false, not empty -> true. Done.

Answer (score 4):

Empty list evaluates to `False` and non-empty list evaluates to `True`.

`if list1 and list2:`

is equivalent to:

`if list1 is not empty and list2 is not empty`:

---

### [List of falsy values in python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

- None
- False
- zero of any numeric type, for example, `0`, `0L`, `0.0`, `0j`.
- any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.
- any empty mapping, for example, `{}`.
- instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a
  `__nonzero__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False.

All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are always true.

Answer (score 1):

If `list_a` is empty, then `list_a and list_b` will evaluate to `list_a`, otherwise it will evaluate to `list_b`. For example:

```
>>> [1] and [2]
[2]
>>> [] and [2]
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Ashwini answer, you can use `bool` inbuilt function to check what a given object will evaluate to.

```
>>> bool([])
False
>>> bool([1,2,3])
True
>>> bool('')
False
>>> bool('hello')
True
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as though it's a logical boolean statement. In Python, when building an If statement, boolean statements have an interesting logical shorthand:

```
bool = True;

If bool:
    return "Blah!"
```

Is the same as:

```
bool = True;

If bool==True:
    return "Blah!"
```

The statement `If *[boolean]*` is a cooler way of saying `If *[boolean]* is True`. In that same way, the statement `If *![boolean]*` is a cooler way of saying `If *[boolean]* is False`, because `!` is the logical `NOT` operator.
It takes a little time to acclimate to this logic but once you do, it makes your code a lot nicer looking.

So why do the lists do this like a boolean value should?

Since Python doesn't have explicit type declaration, every data type has a boolean representation. For lists like `rejected_users` and `allowed_users`, if the lists are empty `{}`'s, it returns `False` and if NOT empty, it returns `True`. Thus, the english translation of

```
if self.rejected_users and self.allowed_users:
```

should read:

```
if self.rejected_users is NOT empty AND if self.allowed_users is NOT empty:
```

I hope this helps.